# Correct use of "rid of"

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, predicate-adjectives

From what I understood, "rid of" is used when I want to express that particular object will be disposed of something. "Get rid of something," on the other hand, does not specify the object.
According to the aforementioned, I found few examples that I do not understand:

> Need to rid of this yeast infection fast? (Should not this be "get rid of.."?)

> He will rid of it. (Is that correct? It is neither "get rid" nor "rid something of something.")

I found both of these examples on the Internet; it can be easily informal. I would just like to know whether I am right here.

Answer (score 5):

Both your examples should be *get rid of*: I suspect a typo.  There is a construction *need rid of something*, short for *need to be rid of*; but it's almost entirely obsolete.

And you can *rid **something** of something else*, or free it (*not* 'dispose it') of whatever; rid the dog of fleas, for example, or rid the car of the annoying noise. *Get rid of* was originally a subset of this, something like *get yourself rid of the infection*. But it has pretty much taken over: I wouldn't advise a non-native speaker to use anything except *get rid of*.

Comment: As a reflexive verb, *to rid oneself of something* works, but sounds a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: You can also *be* rid of something, if you are not the agent of the ridding. *My flatmate's ex-boyfriend was a huge mooch; thank goodness they broke up and we're rid of him at last.*

Answer (score 3):

*Rid* is one of those English Zero-inflected monosyllabic verbs ending in *-d* or *-t*; i.e, it uses -Ø ("Zero") as the suffix for both Past and Perfect forms -- its principal parts are *rid, rid, rid*
(compare *see, saw, seen*).

> Other verbs in this category include *hit, hit, hit*; *bid, bid, bid*; *bet, bet, bet*; *burst, burst, burst*; *cost, cost, cost*; and *fit, fit, fit* (though only **intransitive** *fit*: *Those have never fit me properly* ~ **We have never fit them together properly*).

As pointed out, one can say *A rid X of Y*, which is the transitive causative use of *rid*; the passive of this construction is *X was rid of Y by A* (past tense because present tense would have been *A **rids** X of Y*). And, given the meaning of *rid*, that passive transmutes easily into a predicate adjective as a resultant state: *X is (now) rid of Y*.

Every changeable state has an inchoative construction, meaning 'to change into' that state, and the most common construction for that in English uses *get*, in its sense of *come to be* (whence *become*) -- *get* is troublesome in English because it forms the inchoative of both *have* **and** *be*, but we won't consider its *come to have* sense here.

So, the upshot is that *get rid of* has become an idiomatic causative/inchoative form with its own life; the string *rid of* by itself is not a [constituent](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/570796/15299), it's part of *be rid of* and *get rid of*, which are constituents, but *rid* and *of* never occur together as a unit in sentences *She rid the castle of ghosts*.

Executive summary: Don't think of grammar as words or strings; it's Constructions and Constituents that matter.