# Can I say get someone rid of something?

Tags: expressions

Sometimes I want to tell someone stop from doing something, can I just say:

> I want to get Jack rid from smoking.

Comment: Are you asking about "get Jack rid **from** smoking" or "get Jack rid **of** smoking"?

Comment: I would say you would "rid Jack of" something. Henry II of England is said to have complained to his courtiers, "Will no one **rid me of** this turbulent priest?" Whereupon his men took the hint and slaughtered Thomas Becket.

Comment: Relevant (possible dupe): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/67593/8019

Comment: Something I just learned from Dictionary.com: Origin of "rid": 1150–1200;  Middle English, ridden (v.), Old English ge ryddan,  to clear (land). Put "ge" and "ryddan" together and you have "Good riddance." I want Jack to say "Good riddance to his smoking habit."

Answer (score 3):

For one, you get rid *of* something, not *from* it.

For another, it appears to me you get rid of something you have, or even own. Not of something you do. So Jack can get rid of his *bad habit*, perhaps, but telling him to get rid of smoking sounds like a [poorly translated from German](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Smoking#Noun) invitation to undress.

Comment: +1 for the invitation to undress (which, incidentally, does not work only in German, but also in the Scandinavian languages).

Answer (score 1):

Jack cannot *rid himself of smoking*, because smoking is an activity rather than a thing.

But luckily, he may be able to *rid himself of cigarettes*; or even *rid himself of that beastly habit altogether*.